# What is the reduction of the Weil pairing?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

This is a question about the proof of II.4.4 in Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Cruves*. In the proof, the author claims that there is an equality: $$\widetilde{e_E(x,y)} = e_{\tilde{E}}(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$$, where $e_E$ is the Weil pairing on the Tate module for some prime $\ell$ coprime to a prime $\mathfrak{P}$ in the number field over which $E$ is defined, and $e_\tilde{E}$ is Weil pairing on the corresponding Tate module of the reduction $\tilde{E}$ of $E$. There is no elaboration on what is meant by $\widetilde{e_E(x,y)}$. I'm somewhat confused, since $e_E(x,y)$ is an element in $T_\ell(\mu)$, the inverse limit over all the groups $\mu_{\ell^n}$ of $\ell^n$-roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, whereas $e_{\tilde{E}}(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ is $T_\ell(\overline{\mu})$, which I'll use to mean the inverse limit over the groups of $\ell^n$-roots of unity over $\mathbb{R}_p$.

In order to define a reduction map then, it seems that we need to make a choice of primes in each $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\ell^n})$ to reduce by, and it's not clear to me that the construction is independent of the choice of primes. I don't even see immediately why if we *define* the map by $e_E(x,y) \mapsto e_{\tilde{E}}(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ this would be well-defined (i.e. do we know that if $e_E(x,y) = e_E(s,t)$, then $e_{\tilde{E}}(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}) = e_{\tilde{E}}(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$?).

Any help figuring out what Silverman means here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you’re leaving out part of the question: you point out (quite correctly) that one side is undefined, and do not seem to care about the other side, which is equally undefined!

Indeed, the points $x,y$ in the Tate module of $E$ are defined over very large extensions of $K$, so we *also* need to choose a prime to have suitable reductions mod $\mathfrak{P}$. The idea is that these two choices are the same.

Let us fix, once and for all, a prime $P$ of $\overline{K}$ above $\mathfrak{P}$. Then, for $x,y \in T_{\ell}E$, we can see $x,y$ as sequences of points in $\overline{K}$, and thus reduce them mod $P$ to sequences on the residue field of $O_{\overline{K}}/P$ – we have thus defined a reduction map $T_{\ell}E \rightarrow T_{\ell}\tilde{E}$ (which is an isomorphism).

The choice of $P$ also lets us consider a reduction map $T_{\ell}(\mu) \rightarrow T_{\ell}(\tilde{\mu})$.

The claim is that these two reduction maps (they’re isomorphisms, and, remember, they come *from the same choice*) are compatible with the Weil pairing. It shouldn’t be too difficult now to check that the claim is formal.